# Using returned variable in python

Tags: python, function, return

Why doesn't the following allow me to use the `os` variable once it's returned by the function? The `os` module isn't being imported so that shouldn't be an issue at all. When I call the `Begin()` function and print the `os` variable after the function is finished, python says the variable is not defined.

```
def Begin():
    os = raw_input("Choose your operating system:\n[1] Ubuntu\n[2] CentOS\nEnter '1' or     '2': ")
    if os != '1' and os != '2':
        print "Incorrect operating system choice, shutting down..."
        time.sleep(3)
        exit()
    else:
        return os

Begin()
print os
```

Comment: **please** don't use `os` as a variable name -- it's the name of a well-known module.

Answer (score 4):

You have to assign the returned result to an actual variable. The `os` in the function exists only in the function scope, and can't be used outside of it.

```
result = Begin()
print result
```

As @nneonneo mentioned, `os` is a part of the standard library, and a commonly used module, and using `os` as a variable name will confuse a reader, and if `os` is imported, will overwrite it.

Another suggestion:

```
if os != '1' and os != '2':
```

can be written more succintly as

```
if os not in ('1', '2'):
```

This also makes it easier when you have more similar comparisons to make.

Comment: Every time I have an issue...it's a careless mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your code os is a local variable to Begin() as suggested by @nneonneo do not use standard module names.

If you are just trying to print the value you can simply do

```
print Begin()
```

if you need to use the returned value from Begin() then assign it to a variable and you can use it further.